# Rdlc report justify text alignment

Tags: rdlc

I have searched a lot in .Net and not able to find an exact answer for full text justify alignment in textbox when generating PDF reports using rdlc file.
Kindly let me the full code.for.workaround

Comment: From the origin of black hole, from the time of stone age, this question is searching for its answer. There are several forums and programmers including me looking for the solution. Unfortunately, Microsoft has the evergreen answer "NO, IT IS NOT POSSIBLE".